# Testing Internationalised Dates in Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, activesupport

I have some business logic in a controller that I want to test that involves setting two values to today's date and yesterday's date.

Initially I had a passing test that essentially looked like this;

**controller:**

```
def wibble
  @start_time = Date.yesterday
end
```

**test:**

```
it 'blah blah'
  get :wibble
  assigns(:start_date).should eq(Date.yesterday)
end
```

**But a new requirement has been added that means the date should be i18n'd**, which means that the controller is returning back something different.

### My Thoughts

I had thought about mocking the variables, because I could only care that they are set to something, but then the business logic of Today and Yesterday isn't being exercised.

I also considered forcing i18n on the test, but this seems way to brittle.

Can anyone suggest a good way to test this?

Comment: Saying "business logic in a controller" often suggests that you should move that logic to a model. Do you think doing so would make the testing more easy or obvious?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "forcing i18n on the test", and why would turning i18n on during the test make it more brittle?